# Looking for comment plugin

Tags: plugins, comments

I know that it is possible to let user comment entries using the guest entries plugin or to implement a third-party solution.

But I wonder if is someone working on a dedicated comment plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know of any comment plugins yet but the easiest thing to do is to [Integrate Disqus](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/integrating-disqus). You just drop the embed code in and paste in your entry ID.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still looking, have a look at [Comments](https://github.com/engram-design/Comments). Any suggestions/comments very welcome!